# How can we distinguish between "actual" singularities in a metric from singularities that can be eliminated via a switch to different coordinates?

Tags: differential-geometry

We know that if on the Euclidean plane we use polar coordinates, the metric $$dr^2+r^2d\theta^2$$ has a singularity at $r=0$ (e.g., the volume element is zero at $r=0$, and $g^{\theta\theta}$ diverges as $r^{-2}$) This is of course an artifact of working with polar coordinates. A switch to Cartesian coordinates cures the problem. However, in a general case it may not be obvious that the singularity disappears in a different coordinate system. So the question is: Is there a general criterion that can be used to discriminate between uncurable singularities from curable singularities?

Comment: Perhaps consider [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9990/cone-angles-for-riemannian-metrics-in-polar-coordinates) and [this](https://math.berkeley.edu/~lott/ricci).

Comment: This is essentially related to the fact that Cartesian coordinates $(x,y)$ are smooth **global** coordinates for $\mathbb{R}^2$, while the change of coordinates $x = r\cos\theta, y = r\sin\theta$ is not smooth at $r=0$, so that polar coordinates alone do not comprise a smooth atlas for the manifold $\mathbb{R}^2$. So indeed, when you define $g=dr^2+r^2d\theta^2$, you have only defined a local object on the set $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$. Since Cartesian coordinates are global, and smooth extensions always exist, you can extend globally once you change coordinates.

Comment: This is not answerable until you define precisely what kind of singularities you are willing to consider. An example is not enough, you have to have a definition.